# unexpected solr result set when searching for a keyword

Tags: search, solr, match, ranking

i am trying to do simple search query in solr however one of the result set is actually strange,

when searching for
poi_name:hamad

i am getting good results but among them
"early education center h b k u" with a score:1.8473094

Any idea why this has a score in the first place?
poi_name field is of Textfiled type

Answer (score 0):

I found a synonym entry of h => hamad that explains why i am getting this result